# N3 Activation Issue

Tags: dji-sdk

I have bought  a DJI N3 flight controller. I want to use the Onboard SDK on it. But I am facing problems with the activation. I have got the APP ID and Key from the site. I have edited the sdk.launch file and UserConfig.txt in the SDK packages. On running the launch file, I am getting the following result.

```
trishant@Eurus-Holmes:~/catkin_ws/src$ roslaunch dji_sdk sdk.launch
... logging to /home/trishant/.ros/log/a8788da0-05e8-11e9-89ab-2c6e8522ef61/roslaunch-Eurus-Holmes-27223.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Eurus-Holmes:41551/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dji_sdk/align_time: False
 * /dji_sdk/app_id: 1066401
 * /dji_sdk/app_version: 1
 * /dji_sdk/baud_rate: 921600
 * /dji_sdk/enc_key: f9b36add116633854...
 * /dji_sdk/serial_name: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /dji_sdk/use_broadcast: False
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    dji_sdk (dji_sdk/dji_sdk_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[dji_sdk-1]: started with pid [27240]

STATUS/1 @ init, L55: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyUSB0 with baudrate 921600...

STATUS/1 @ init, L65: ...Serial started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L706: Device Serial No. = 0DBDF5E00200BS

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L708: Hardware = N3

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L709: Firmware = 3.3.8.39

ERRORLOG/1 @ initVirtualRC, L1067: Virtual RC is not supported on this platform!

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1277: version 0x3030827

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: activate
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetActivationMSG, L705: DJIGO_APP_NOT_CONNECTED_ERROR

ERRORLOG/1 @ activate, L1302: Failed to activate please retry SET 0x0 ID 0x1 code 0x4
[ERROR] [1545484435.702713621]: drone activation error
[ERROR] [1545484435.702863772]: Vehicle initialization failed
^C[dji_sdk-1] killing on exit

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: removePackage
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetSubscribeMSG, L739: SUBSCRIBER_ILLEGAL_DATA_LENGTH

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: removePackage
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetSubscribeMSG, L739: SUBSCRIBER_ILLEGAL_DATA_LENGTH

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: removePackage
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetSubscribeMSG, L739: SUBSCRIBER_ILLEGAL_DATA_LENGTH

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: removePackage
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetSubscribeMSG, L739: SUBSCRIBER_ILLEGAL_DATA_LENGTH

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: reset
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetSubscribeMSG, L739: SUBSCRIBER_ILLEGAL_DATA_LENGTH
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Am I missing some steps? Is DJI GO compulsory for activation?
I have connected the computer to API pins and followed ROS Onboard instructions (https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/sample-setup.html#ros-onboard-computer)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. You can activate without the DJI App.